# Any way to get cookie from safari OR other browser?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get cookie from safari in iOS, Any way to get cookie from safari OR other browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, App can not access other apps data. This has to do with privacy.